# System.Net.Socket.Socket.AcceptAsync equivalent in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, sockets, async-await

I have this method in .net

```
    public static SocketAwaitable AcceptAsync(this Socket socket,
                                              SocketAwaitable awaitable)
    {
        awaitable.Reset();
        if (!socket.**AcceptAsync(awaitable.EventArgs))**
            awaitable.WasCompleted = true;
        return awaitable;
    }
```

Porting this code into silverlight results in this error

> Error 1   'System.Net.Sockets.Socket' does not contain a definition for 'AcceptAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SLAsyncAwaitSocketProxy.SocketExtensions.AcceptAsync(System.Net.Sockets.Socket, SLAsyncAwaitSocketProxy.SocketAwaitable)' has some invalid arguments

From what i understand, silverlight doesnt have System.Net.Socket.Socket.AcceptAsync. Are there any equivalent method that i can use? Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Accept` is used to receive incoming socket connections; this is not possible on Silverlight or most other hosted platforms for security reasons.

You'll need to connect *from* your Silverlight app to a server instead. Once a connection is made, data can flow bidirectionally.

One possible alternative is SignalR.

Comment: Thank you. That make sense. I was blindly porting a .net to silverlight. BTW, during my research on async await socket programming, i did encounter your blog. Very nice and informative.